# Keyboard is not working Why?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, keys

My keyboard has some keys that are not working like (/ spacebar N B ). Sometimes they work, and sometimes they don't.

Comment: If only some keys are showing problems sometimes, it’s probably dust in the keyboard. Depending on the type of keyboard, you may be able to clean it with a toothbrush (that you won’t use for teeth later) 

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release, but I'd suggest booting *live* media built from a different *stack* to your *unstated* installed system to ensure it's not related to the software stack you've got installed (ie. different OS & release to what you have installed; or at least a very different release). If it occurs in both; it's almost guaranteed related to hardware.